# Could upgrade from Quickfix.net.1.7 to QuickFIXn.1.10 require NO code change?

Tags: .net, quickfixn

I just upgraded from a 6+ years old  Quickfix.net.1.7 (dll) to QuickFIXn.1.10 and my app ran with NO code changes?

Can that be possible?

I "removed" the old quickfix from references and installed new from Nuget.

Could it still be using the old library? Or has structure of Quickfix objects not changed in all that time?

> EDIT 1

Does anyone have the original source files for Quickfix.net.1.7?

Comment: If only the minor version increased I would *expect* that no code change is necessary.

Comment: Great - that is comforting...